# Symfony 3.4 Array to string conversion when trying to display flash messages

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-3.4

I have to be missing something here, just trying to set a flash message in a new project.

In controller:

```php
$this->addFlash(
    'success',
    'Your entry was added!'
);
```

In my template, I include:

```
{% for message in app.flashes(['success', 'notice']) %}
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <p align="center">
            <b>Success! </b><br/>
            {{ message }}
        </p>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I get the following exception every time:

> "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion")."

[image]

I checked the length of **message** and it's zero. If I dump it, it's an empty array as it should be. Anyone see what I'm missing here, driving me crazy. Also, if I set a flash message it gives me the same error.

Comment: What is your symfony version? Look this article. It tells you can  filter by multiple type after symfony 3.3. https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-improved-flash-messages

Comment: Current 3.4 release. I copied the code from that page, so figured it would work. Have never had this problem in any other projects.

Comment: In your twig template the `for` loop `message` is an array, so change `message` in `messages` and add another `for` loop to show each message (_as showed in the docs_).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read and display several types of flash messages:

```php
{% for label, messages in app.flashes(['success', 'notice']) %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <p align="center">
                <b>Success! </b><br/>
                {{ message }}
            </p>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#managing-the-session

Comment: Good lord I'm an idiot. 10 straight hours and I apparently can't see the most obvious thing ever... Thank you